# Android fill color in transparent image

Tags: android, android-image

i am working on Image fill color . i have a Transparent image , i need to fill color in image according to percentage of level complete , i don't have idea how to do it , can any one suggest me.

thanks in advance

Comment: was my answer of any help ?

Comment: its help full for  idea . i am studying on  ColorMatrixColorFilter.lets see what happen for next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for  help i just did in simple way , i am adjusting hight in run time of first imageview .

```
    android:layout_width="300dp"

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_height="300dp"
    >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVie"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/masking"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with the opacity of your image, you are looking for the alpha parameter !

```
yourImageView.setAlpha(0.5) // alpha is between 0 and 1 (fully transparent/opaque)
```

If you want to change the color of your image, you'll have to work with ColorMatrixFilter :

```
ColorMatrix myColorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
    1,0,0,RGBValR, //red value
    0,1,0,RGBValG,
    0,0,1,RGBValB,
    0,0,0,1});
ColorMatrixColorFilter myFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(myColorMatrix);
myImageView.setColorFilter(myfilter);
```

Comment: From where we find ColorMatrix class and ColorMAtrixCoolorFilter class ?

Comment: It's an android class ! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

To set background color for a transparent image, `backgroundTint` attribute can be used.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_star_white"
      android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```